# PHP: Ensure that an array contains objects from only a certain class

Tags: php, arrays, class

In some of my setters, I pass an array of objects. I would like to ensure that it only contains instances from a given class. Reading the doc, here is what I do :

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

class ErrorFoo
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

$arrayObject = Array();

array_push($arrayObject, new Foo());
array_push($arrayObject, new Foo());
array_push($arrayObject, new ErrorFoo());

$error = false;
foreach ($arrayObject as $obj)
{
    if ( $obj instanceof Foo ) 
    {
        echo "ok" . '<br>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "error" . '<br>';
        $error = true;  
    }
}
```

Do you know a simpler way than iterate through the array like this?

Comment: Not sure if always setting `$error= true;` helps.

Comment: oups, corrected

Comment: As part of your setter function you can validate the passed object type? Throwing exceptions if the type doesnt match what you want. Doing this will ensure the object returned in any getters are of the type expected.

Comment: @Goon3r If I pass an array as parameter, then the passed object type is Array, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `array_map` or `array_walk` for this:

https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Example of array_map:

```
function isInstanceOfFoo($n)
{
    if(!($n instanceof Foo)) {
      throw new Exception('Error');
    }
}

$ArrayObject = Array();

array_push($ArrayObject, new Foo());
array_push($ArrayObject, new Foo());
array_push($ArrayObject, new ErrorFoo());

array_map(isInstanceOfFoo, $ArrayObject);
```

https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Example of array_walk:

```
function isInstanceOfFoo($n, $k)
{
    if(!($n instanceof Foo)) {
      throw new Exception('Error');
    }
}
array_walk($ArrayObject, isInstanceOfFoo);
```

Comment: the links are /de/ instead of /en/ can't edit that because It needs at least 6 characters

Comment: You could extend this to pass the class name - so becomes `function isInstanceOf( $class, $n)` and test becomes `$n instanceOf $class`.  It's like using Javas generics.

Answer (score 4):

Create a class that extends [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), redefine its [`offsetSet()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetset.php) method and do the check in it. Use this class instead of a plain array to store the objects of type `Foo`.

```
class ArrayOfFoo extends ArrayObject
{
    public function offsetSet($index, $newval)
    {
        // Verify the input 
        if (! $newval instanceof Foo) {
            // do something
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid type');
        }

        // Let the parent class do its job
        parent::offsetSet($index, $newval);
    }
}
```

This code throws an exception when the object of type `ErrorFoo` is added to the array:

```
$ArrayObject = new ArrayOfFoo();

$ArrayObject[] = new Foo();
$ArrayObject[] = new Foo();
// This throws an exception
$ArrayObject[] = new ErrorFoo();
```

An instance of the [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class can be used in the same way an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is used (setting, unsetting and fetching values from it). Its method [`getArrayCopy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.getarraycopy.php) can be used to get an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) that can be passed as argument to functions that expect arrays (`explode()`, f.e.)

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is using variadics to enforce types. It's an array inside the function, but not outside:

```
function doSomething(MyObject ...$array)
{
     // $array contains only MyObject instances in it
}

doSomething(new MyObject, new MyObject, new MyObject);
```